# Entendendo as rotas de MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou para iniciar um projeto em MVC 5 .NET porém não entendo muito bem com funciona esse *framework* de rotas.

Estou acostumado com ASP.NET 4.5 onde sei que:

O  `.aspx` é o front-end.

O `.aspx.cs` é o *code behind* (back-end) do código.

O `.cs` é classe com o banco de dados.

Gostaria de uma explicação menos técnica  sobre cada rota.
E como elas se relacionam.

**Model
View 
Controller**

Comment: Estou achando um pouco amplo ou duplicata.

Comment: @Maniero o Stack não me apontou como duplicada.

Comment: @IgorCarreiro de uma lida nesse artigo aqui ó:https://www.devmedia.com.br/entendendo-as-rotas-no-asp-net-mvc/29861